# Php get website host

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a link to my website host like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>"><?php echo $WebsiteTitle; ?></a>
```

but for some reason that generates this

```
http://localhost/mywebsite-directory/localhost
```

Any idea why are 2 **localhosts** generated?

Comment: Where are you assigning value to `$WebsiteTitle;` ? Can you show that ?

Comment: You are possibly overwriting `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. Try searching for `HTTP_HOST` in your code, you might find a line which overwrites the initial value (which should be nothing but `localhost`.)

Comment: that's just a variable like this $WebsiteTitle = "Home";

Comment: Check your /etc/hosts file and make sure it doesn't list 'localhost' in there twice

Comment: Why not just make put the actual link of the host? its not like you change hosting every hour right?

Comment: Until you fix it, try using `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` in lieu of the solution.  And @Deadpool he's probably making a re-usable script for other people

Comment: I checked the code i'm not overwriting $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] anywhere

Comment: I also uploaded the website on a .com domain and same problem there too

Comment: Post a copy of your .htaccess file (assuming nothing secretive is in there)

Comment: @Deryck i don't have one.

Comment: Is the .com version still up so we can see it in action?  And did you try my SERVER_NAME instead of HTTP_HOST?

Comment: Elaborating the problem would help a bit. What was the variable `$WebsiteTitle` assigned to previously?

Comment: `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $WebsiteTitle);` and stop guessing

Comment: @kevin Ok here's everything i have a website with 1 index.php file and the template folder with 3 files header.php, sidebar.php and footer.php, and i include them all inside the index.php file. And the problem is in the template's header.php file where i'm trying to get the website host as a link for the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your a href is pointing to 'localhost' which 
gives you link 'http://localhost/my-websitedir/[localhost]'

try doing:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/mywebsite-directory'; ?>"><?php echo $WebsiteTitle; ?></a>
```

Comment: my website is not directly in the local host, but in 'localhost/mywebsite-directory'

Comment: well i've updated the answer. The point is that $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']='localhost', browser just appends it to current URI as it has no slash or protocol at the beginning of it